# Different ModelField handling

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a scenario where a user need to enter a type of contribution. It can be cash or material. Based on his contribution type, I need to store the cash in IntegerField or material in CharField. How can I do it without making two fields in the model and leaving one always as empty field.

```
class Contribution(models.Model):

    CONTRIBUTION_TYPE_CASH = "cash"
    CONTRIBUTION_TYPE_MATERIAL = "material"

    CONTRIBUTION_TYPE_CHOICES = [
        (CONTRIBUTION_TYPE_CASH, _("cash")),
        (CONTRIBUTION_TYPE_MATERIAL, _("material"))
    ]


    contributor = models.ForeignKey(Contributor, related_name="donor", verbose_name=_("contributor"))
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CONTRIBUTION_TYPE_CHOICES, verbose_name=_("contribution type"))
```

Comment: that 's not very clear. Could you show us what you would like to have? what do you means by "without making two fields in the model and leaving one always as empty field"?

Comment: In the above model, based on user selection of type.
If type is "cash". user's amount should be saved as a number.
If type is "material". user's donated materials should be saved as a char.

Comment: yeah but what is the problem? "How can I do it without making two fields in the model and leaving one always as empty field." What's does it mean?

Comment: Based on type, i will get an input which can be a Char or an Integer.
If i add two fields to this model, one to store cash_amount and other to store material_contributed. Always one of them will be empty as a countribution will either be one of these two. That is a waste.

Answer (score 0):

First variant, keep a single `CharField` and make sure you properly validate input depending on `type`. You will have to deal with strings all the time, even if the actual value is a number.

Second variant, use model inheritance and define two different models, one for material contributions and another for cash contributions. You can use an abstract parent in which case you'd have to manually merge the two querysets for getting a global contribution list. **Or** you could use a concrete parent and use a third party package such as `django_polymorphic` to seamlessly deal with inherited instances. Either way you'd have to create the apropriate model instance in your backend, even if you use the same dynamic form in your frontend.